# Best way to approach making REST calls until it finally sends?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am making a script with makes REST calls to make changes to a data pipe-lining  service. This can mean I am making roughly 120 changes every time the script runs. When ONE change occurs, the service must rebalance. During this rebalance, the endpoint is unreachable--which means that no rest calls can be made for the remaining changes and leading the script to break. What is the best way to approach this polling with Spring boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Spring Retry at: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry

Answer (score 0):

If you can extend the REST API, maybe you should consider adding a `/batch-changes` ressource which would take the list of all changes as input. Thus you can apply all of them at once, reducing downtime and resolving your issue.